# Not able to npm installation path

Tags: node.js

I have installed node.js. But I am not able to install npm. After a lot of googling, I think the problem is that it is looking for npm in the wrong directory. So, can you tell me how to change the path?

```bash
PS C:\Users\anuri\OneDrive\Desktop\react> npm install
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\anuri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: You can manually add the correct npm directory to your PATH environment variable.